# Why does powershell automatically append my strings together and pass it as the first argument?

Tags: powershell

I've got the following code:

```
function printVars($var1, $var2)
{
  Write-Host "var1: $var1"
  Write-Host "var2: $var2"
}

printVars ('asdf', 'qwer')
```

It produces this result:

```
var1: asdf qwer
var2:
```

I am expecting this:

```
var1: asdf
var2: qwer
```

Why is it doing that and how do I get it to do what I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `('asdf','qwer')` gets treated as an array, so `$var1` gets the array and `$var2` is empty.

Do `printVars 'asdf' 'qwer'`

Even if you don't have the parantheses and have just the comma, it is an array.

Try this:

```
$b ="one","two"
$b.GetType()
```

Answer (score 3):

The correct answer has already been provided but for those looking for further information I tore this off my PowerShell quick reference chart. This assumes function f's signature is `f($a, $b, $c)`:

[image: syntax pitfalls of a function call]

Thus, one can call a function with space-separated *positional* parameters or order-independent *named* parameters. The other pitfalls reveal that you need to be cognizant of commas, parentheses, and white space.

For further reading see my recent article [Down the Rabbit Hole- A Study in PowerShell Pipelines, Functions, and Parameters](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/down-the-rabbit-hole--a-study-in-powershell-pipelines,-functions,-and-parameters/) just published on Simple-Talk.com. The article contains a link to the quick reference/wall chart as well.

Answer (score 0):

I see now. I'm calling the function wrong.

It should be this:

```
printVars 'asdf' 'qwer'
```

The quotes could be removed too.

Although it looks like the brace-languages like Perl and C calling a function is like calling another command using most shells.

When I put the comma in there it appends the strings together into one string and passes that as the first argument.

Comment: It doesn't append the strings ( though that is what happens in the write-host ). It gets treated as an array. See my answer.

Comment: If you leave out the parens and only use a comma does that also create an array?